# Baseline alignment causes UIButton to not be tappable

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton, autolayout

I have a label and a button on my screen. The button is aligned to the label via the auto layout baseline setting. When I run the app on an iOS 7.1 simulator, this is what happens:

[image]

Notice how the button's background (light blue) is all the way at the top of the screen. Tapping on the Button's text does nothing, but tapping on the light blue square trigger's the button's action.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is a bug in iOS 7.1 when aligning buttons with attributed text via their baseline.

There are several ways to fix this:

- Use iOS 8: When I tried the same exact behavior on iOS 8.4 simulator, everything worked properly.
- Don't use an attributed string.
- Align via the center instead of baseline.